# If id repeats then changing the repeated id using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an xml input with repeated id's as below

```
<root>
<p>text 1</p>
<text id="Read-R1">
<p>sample 1</p>
</text>
<p>text 2</p>
<text id="Read-R2">
<p>sample 2</p>
</text>
<p>text 3</p>
<text id="Read-R1">
<p>sample 3</p>
</text>
<p>text 4</p>
<text id="Read-R2">
<p>sample 3</p>
</text>
<p>text 5</p>
<text id="Read-R1">
<p>sample 5</p>
</text>
<text id="Read-R3">
<p>sample 3</p>
</text>
</root>
```

repeated id i want to change append -01 to the repeated id only first id same as it is:
output as:

```
<root>
<p>text 1</p>
<text id="Read-R1">
<p>sample 1</p>
</text>
<p>text 2</p>
<text id="Read-R2">
<p>sample 2</p>
</text>
<p>text 3</p>
<text id="Read-R1-01">
<p>sample 3</p>
</text>
<p>text 4</p>
<text id="Read-R2-01">
<p>sample 3</p>
</text>
<p>text 5</p>
<text id="Read-R1-02">
<p>sample 5</p>
</text>
<text id="Read-R3">
<p>sample 3</p>
</text>
</root>
```

Please suggest the xslt to append -01 for the repeated ids
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wil work with a bonus, that if there are more then one with that same @id it still creates unique ids.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <xsl:template match="text[@id]">
    <xsl:variable name="sId" select="@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="iPrecedingIdsWithSameValue" select="count(preceding-sibling::text[@id=$sId])"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="id" select="if($iPrecedingIdsWithSameValue gt 0) then concat(@id,'-',format-number($iPrecedingIdsWithSameValue,'00')) else @id"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The id may repeat two three time also before or after but first id should be as it is remaining id''s need to appended with -01 and -02...

Comment: @User515: that is the how this xsl is working.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following key and template

```
  <xsl:key name="id" match="text" use="@id"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="text[not(. is key('id', @id)[1])]/@id">
    <xsl:attribute 
      name="{name()}"
      select="concat(., '-', format-number(index-of(key('id', .)[position() gt 1]/generate-id(), generate-id(..)), '00'))"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

plus the identity transformation (either declared in XSLT 3 by `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` or spelled out as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please see my edited id formats. please suggest the xslt code

Comment: @User515, no, sorry, don't change your requirements after an answer implementing the original ones has been posted. Try to adapt the code on your own. If you really fail, post a new question with details of what you tried and how it failed.